# My widgets aren't appearing on my Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I found some PHP code in a blog tutorial that has enabled widgets in my theme. The code seems like it should work, because since adding it, the widgets option has appeared under the "appearance" tab in the sidebar. The tutorial also provided some code to put in the area that you want the widgets to appear – in my case the footer, which I have included below. Nothing I add in the widgets drag and drop section is showing up, including the titles etc. I have tried adding a few different things and haven't had any success. There are no errors showing in the console. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Added to my functions.php

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer',
        'id'   => 'footer',
        'description'   => 'Here you can add widgets to the footer',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h6>',
        'after_title'   => '</h6>'
    ));

}
```

Added to my footer.php

```
<?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('widgetized-area')) : else : ?>

    <div class="pre-widget">
        <p><strong>Widgetized Area</strong></p>
        <p>This panel is active and ready for you to add some widgets via the WP Admin</p>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

My header

```
<header class="header">
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <a href="#">
        <img class="standard logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo-2.png">
        <img class="white logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo_White.png"></a>
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <img class="menu button" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Menu.png">
    <!-- HEADER NAVIGATION MENU -->
    <nav class="header-nav">
        <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-463">
                    <a href="#">WORK</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-584"><a href="#">LANDSCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-473"><a href="#">SEASCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-478"><a href="#">MACRO</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-477"><a href="#">CITIES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-475"><a href="#">LONG EXPOSURE</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-480"><a href="#">MISCELLANEOUS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-10"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-464"><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-923">
                    <a href="#">SOCIAL</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-11"><a target="_blank" href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-924"><a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-15"><a target="_blank" href="#">FLICKR</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li id="menu-item-14"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: View source.  You will see a "Fatal Error" message at the bottom (assuming you have PHP error reporting turned on).  That Fatal Error information will tell you what, where, and why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply – how do I turn PHP error reporting on? I haven't heard of this, I always thought that errors only showed in the console. Does it specify whether the error is with the code above?

Comment: Did you view source? It's possible it's already on.  For WordPress, first check your `wp-config.php` file, and be sure that `define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE)` is set - if it's `FALSE`, then errors are being hidden.

Comment: I did, and there were three mentions of the word "error" that I could find. One of them was with the instagram feed plugin that I coincidentally wanted to add to a widget, so I've deactivated it for now. The other two seem to be non-consequential for now (I hope) – just something to do with an email address in my page builder. I don't actually have a wp-config.php file as this is a self built theme and I still have quite a few things to learn. I've added that to the list of things to do though. I'm thinking possibly a PHP checker programme I found online might do the trick.

Comment: If you are running WordPress, you do in fact have a wp-config.php file.  Look in your site root (the same folder where you will see `index.php`, `wp-content` folder, `wp-admin`, etc.)

Comment: You're right, I found it. I've just changed it to `define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE)` however I still can't see any new errors coming up in the view source page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that dynamic_sidebar(); needs to call your registered sidebar by id so:

```
dynamic_sidebar('footer');
```

not

```
dynamic_sidebar('widgetized-area');
```

See [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) and [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) from the codex